# JAXB and File Locking

Tags: xml, jaxb, file-locking

I'm trying to lock file before unmarshalling and release after marshalling.

```
public T lockedReadingFromFile(String filePath, Class<T> clas) {
    T object = null;
    JAXBContext context = null;
    Unmarshaller unMarshaller = null;
    try {
        fileToBlock = new File(filePath);
        file = new RandomAccessFile(fileToBlock, "rw");
        FileChannel fileChannel = file.getChannel();
        fileLock = fileChannel.tryLock();
        if (fileLock != null) {
            System.out.println("File is locked");
        }
        context = JAXBContext.newInstance(clas);
        unMarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        object = (T) unMarshaller.unmarshal(fileToBlock);

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return object;
}
```

But code throws exception during unmarshalling in line `object = (T) unMarshaller.unmarshal(fileToBlock);`

```
File is locked
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file]
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

```
unMarshaller.unmarshal(fileToBlock)
```

Here, unmarshaller is provided with the `java.io.File` argument, so it tries to read the file by creating new inputstream on its own.

Instead, use `FileInputStream` to read the XML using `JAXB`.

```
   FileInputStream fileToBlockStream = new FileInputStream(fileToBlock);
   FileChannel fileChannel = fileToBlockStream.getChannel();
   fileLock = fileChannel.tryLock();

   unMarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
   object = (T) unMarshaller.unmarshal(fileToBlockStream);
```